# Swift: How do I create a sequence of 'if' statements?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I want to know how to write a sequence in an if statement, like I would as a sequence of actions? For example:

If I have `var touchedBool = Bool()`, how do I create an if statement that says:

`if touchedBool == true` **FOLLOWED BY** `touchedBool == false` **THEN**

```
{
   // This happens.
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *Followed By*? An else/else if statement?

Comment: @AndrewL.- I would only like something to happen if the touchedBool is true, but then followed by a false. So if I had touchedBool = true inside by touchesBegan and a touchedBool = false inside my touchesEnded, I would then want something to happen not when I touch or release, but when I touch, FOLLOWED by releasing my finger.

Comment: @AndrewL.- Basically I'm not after a "&&" because that means it happens when they are both true and false. I want it to happen if they both follow one another.

Comment: Please explain clearly *in the question*.

Comment: I'm not picking up what you're putting down. You can use && to check multiple conditions and different equalities such as false or true

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question for what you are trying to accomplish, Take a look at the different events on buttons, you might need to use these events to accomplish what you are after (whatever that is)

Comment: So you want something to happened if at some point in time the user was touching something (touchedBool = true) and then stopping touching the something (touchedBool = false)? P.S. You don't need to put the variable type in the variable name - just use isTouched, for example. Else you'll have to have scoreInt, playerPositionCGPoint, playerShipSKSpriteNode etc :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there should be a better way to accomplish what you really want, but here is the thing I believe you are looking for:

```
var touchedBool = false {
    didSet {
        if oldValue && !touchedBool {
            print("Boom") // Do your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the way to do it, but I think you have your logic backwards,  he wants oldValue to be true, and newValue to be false, then trigger some event

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
var someBool = true

if someBool {
// Do something
} else {
// Do Something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For your example, a simple if-else would be fine:

```
var anyBool: Bool = true

if anyBool == true {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

This would work fine for bools, but gets cumbersome for something with multiple options other than true of false. For this, I would recommend a switch statement;

```
var anyInt = 1

switch anyInt {
    case 1:
        //do something
    case 2:
        //do something
    case 3:
        //do something
    case 4:
        //do something
    default:
        //do something else
}
```

Switch statements are a lot more flexible as well